# Sitecore: What is the advantage of Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.Redirect over Response.Redirect?

Tags: asp.net, redirect, sitecore

Is there any advantage or difference when using...

```
Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.Redirect(string path)
```

...instead of...

```
Response.Redirect(string url)
```

...for redirecting?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is one major difference. The Sitecore method will check that there is in fact a `HttpContext`. Other than that there is no difference as `Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.Redirect(string path)` in turn calls `HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(path, true)`;

However, if you call `Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.Redirect(path, false)` and the path you provide is the same page you on then no redirect will happen.